# What does the differential $l$-form equation mean?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have this equation which is from [here](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Lr8zo2caBWYC&pg=PA209&lpg=PA209&dq=wess%20zumino%20consistency%20condition%20lie%20algebra&source=bl&ots=JitAps0BhC&sig=aErvJGCdpiXogEUmGsYmJqSeO8Q&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=wess%20zumino%20consistency%20condition%20lie%20algebra&f=false) (equation 12.63) of the book "Differential Geometry, Gauge Theories, and Gravity". Can somebody explain what it means? thanks!

the equation is:

[image]

Comment: It is a definition.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the definition of the [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative), which generalizes the gradient operation from old-fashioned calculus on $\mathbb{R}^n$.